# What is the difference between module, plugin and component in Java?

Tags: architecture

What is the difference between **module**, **plugin** and **component** in Java?

Comment: This is not a Java related question, but a software architecture one. You can have modules, plugins and components in lots of languages.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Programmers.SE

Comment: The terms module,plug-in and component are very broad terms. A plug-in is a module and a component is a module that includes plug-ins a.s.o. Also Java doesn't offer direct support for any of the concepts per se. I think you first need to read-up on the basic concepts of Java Classes and Java Packages.

Comment: @Jonas I agree, voted to migrate it

Answer (score 12):

In plain Java, your organizational units are just **packages** and **classes**.

Some frameworks allow you to define these higher level organizational units in terms of those above, and can manage their lifecycle.

- A module a quite generic terminology for a related set of classes that perform a task, and are usually bundled together in a jar file.
- A plugin is, like its name says, a piece of software that you can plug into an application to provide new functionality. Plugins usually implement well defined API's and are reactive (that is, they provide services that the main application can use).
- A component is any piece of software designed to be reusable.

So you can have modules that contain plugins and components, components that are plugins, etc.

Comment: Thanks fortran, It makes more **sense** to me now

Comment: you are welcome, but remember that module, plugin and component are just names given to some architectural concepts; they are nothing intrinsic to the Java language.

Comment: I've been searching for a plain English, concrete distinction between components and modules for half of my career. This is an awesome answer and I couldn't agree more (+1 good sir).